# SQL consulta para evitar duplicado según fecha

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buenas, estoy haciendo una consulta en donde necesito traer todas las "actividades" que tienen cierto estado (id=2) , el problema es que cuando hago mi consulta de acuerdo a una tabla que almacena el historial por los que ha pasado una "actividad", me regresa bien los registro, pero algunas actividades han pasado 2 veces por ese estado, por lo que me regresa los 2 estados por lo que paso 2 veces (duplicando mi información para esos casos específicos).
Tengo disponible un atributo de la tabla que tiene la fecha para tales casos por lo que necesito ese registro con la fecha mas nueva, alguna ayuda por favor.

Lo que necesito es tener los registro que tengo seleccionados (en la foto marcados con azul, fila 2 y 3), pero me regresa todo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta que aplico es la siguiente:

```
SELECT *
FROM UsuarioEstadoActividadPlanificada ue 
INNER JOIN ActividadPlanificada a ON ue.idActividadPlanificada = a.idActividadPlanificada 
INNER JOIN ActividadGenerica ag ON a.idActividadGenerica = ag.idActividadGenerica 
INNER JOIN UsuarioActividadPlanificada uap ON uap.idActividadPlanificada = ue.idActividadPlanificada 
INNER JOIN DetalleUsuarioEstadoActividadPlanificada du ON du.idActividadPlanificada = ue.idActividadPlanificada 
WHERE uap.idUsuario = 1 AND a.mes <=1 AND a.anio <= 2018 and ue.idEstado = 2 and du.idEstado = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes convertir tu consulta a una tabla derivada, además de agregarle una llamada a `ROW_NUMBER()` para asignarle rangos a los registros según el valor de `fechaEstado`. Luego en la consulta principal puedes filtrar los resultados de tu tabla derivada de modo que solo obtengas los registros con un rango `1`, lo que eliminará los duplicados.

Sin embargo, algo que debes corregir para poder pasar tu consulta a una tabla derivada es que debes reemplazar el `SELECT *` por una lista explícita de columnas. Porque así como lo tienes, te está devolviendo columnas con nombres repetidos, y eso no va a funcionar en una tabla derivada:

```
select *
  from (
    SELECT ue.idActividadPlanificada,
           ue.idEstado,
           ..., -- especifica las columnas que quieres explícitamente
           row_number() over (
               partition by ue.idActividadPlanificada
                   order by ue.fechaEstado desc) as rnk
    FROM UsuarioEstadoActividadPlanificada ue 
    INNER JOIN ActividadPlanificada a ON ue.idActividadPlanificada = a.idActividadPlanificada 
    INNER JOIN ActividadGenerica ag ON a.idActividadGenerica = ag.idActividadGenerica 
    INNER JOIN UsuarioActividadPlanificada uap ON uap.idActividadPlanificada = ue.idActividadPlanificada 
    INNER JOIN DetalleUsuarioEstadoActividadPlanificada du ON du.idActividadPlanificada = ue.idActividadPlanificada 
    WHERE uap.idUsuario = 1 AND a.mes <=1 AND a.anio <= 2018 and ue.idEstado = 2 and du.idEstado = 2
) t
where rnk = 1
```

Nota que estoy asumiendo que la columna `fechaEstado` pertenece a la tabla `UsuarioEstadoActividadPlanificada`, aunque en realidad no has especificado a cual tabla pertenece. Si estoy equivocado, simplemente ajusta el alias `ue` en la expresión `order by ue.fechaEstado desc`.

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias, hice el cambio que dijiste de ue por du y todo bien